# Remove amp; from string in javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I pass a premade URL string as a model to my view in a MVC-project.

I pass the URL as an encodedURIComponent to my controller:

```
window.location = '@Url.Content("~/Default/UserAgreement?registerData=")' + encodeURIComponent(jsonHttp);
```

Then i pass the string as a model

```
   public ActionResult UserAgreement(String registerData)
    {
        return View(null, null, System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(registerData));
    }
```

Then when i try to log it i can't get rid of the `&amp;` None of these work:

```
var urlString = '@Model'.replace("&amp;", "&");
console.log(urlString);

var urlString = decodeURIComponent('@Model');
console.log(urlString);
```

What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably just need to make your replace `global` with the `/g` modifier on a regex, otherwise it will only replace the first instance of `&amp;`:

```
var urlString = '@Model'.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
console.log(urlString);
```

Snippet example:

```js
var str = 'Something &amp; Else &amp;&amp; Here';
alert( str );
alert( str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&') );
```

Comment: Accepted, sorry for the delay!